# angular 2 and Ng-token-Auth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, devise

Hi I'm just starting to learn Angular 2. I understand Angular 1 libraries don't work with Angular 2. Is there a Ng 2 version of Ng-Token-Auth? Does anyone have experience with this, doing authentication using a rails devise-token-auth backend? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [angular2-token library](https://github.com/neroniaky/angular2-token) could handle this task for you, since it is based on Ng-Token-Auth. As of today, there are a few limitations though :

- The library depends on the latest versions of Angular2 (2.0.2 as of today), so it's probably better to be up-to-date in your project too
- angular2-token uses the new Angular 2 router, which is not supported by frameworks such as Ionic 2 yet. However if you're using Ionic 2, you should soon be able to give it a try according to [this post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/new-angular2-router-support-in-ionic2/56847/13).

Hope this helps